# PostSharp: Identify project type of assembly being woven?

Tags: .net, postsharp

Is there a good way to identify the project output type of the target assembly at weaving time? I'm hoping to make an IAspectProvider that applies different aspects depending on whether the target is:

- ASP.NET project (Web Site, Web Application)
- Windows Service
- Desktop/Console Application
- Class Library

Edit: I have accepted an answer as it has identified that there is no built-in mechanism in PostSharp for identifying the type of project being woven; it will either need to be manually specified or obtained in a different way.

Comment: In addition to some other business logic in aspect introduction, for the sake of the easiest example I would particularly like to introduce an assembly attribute to any entry executing assembly type (Web, Desktop, Service), but not to class libraries. I want to apply the IAspectProvider in a global way, rather than adding it to each individual assembly as an assembly-attribute applied aspect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possibility is to pass this information to PostSharp through MSBuild. For example, you can add this to your csproj:

```
<PostSharpProperties>$(PostSharpProperties);ProjectType=Console</PostSharpProperties>
```

In compile time, you can read the property `ProjectType` this way:

```
PostSharpEnvironment.CurrentProject.EvaluateExpression("{$ProjectType}")
```

Docs:

- http://doc.postsharp.net/configuration-msbuild
- http://doc.postsharp.net/configuration-consuming

This is how to pass this information to PostSharp. Another question is how to obtain this information if you wouldn't like hard-code it to the project file manually.

Comment: So my main goal here is to not require manual configuration of new projects (hopefully no guide for everything to add to a new project, besides "Add PostSharp to the project"). After a little more digging, I'm thinking to evaluate the MSBuildFullProjectPath or use the target assembly to programmatically identify the project type? Still not sure if this is best approach or if there's existing samples/tips/etc. that would help me vet this idea

Comment: Another approach is to read the information from PE header of the post-compiled assembly. See https://www.simple-talk.com/blogs/anatomy-of-a-net-assembly-pe-headers/. There are existing libraries for parsing the header. For example https://github.com/secana/PeNet. Mono Cecil might help as well.

Comment: Sadly, I don't think PE will help differentiate Windows Services from Desktop Applications (both are EXEs), nor will it help me differentiate ASP.NET sites from Class Libraries (both are DLLs). I can probably figure something out either with assembly references and exported types, or with the content of the project file. I'll google around more, it sounds like the answer is that PostSharp doesn't have a property or context object that already knows for me. Sadly, I may also have seen something that says IAspectProvider doesn't work with config file multicasting? Have to look into that more